# Is the exponential map globally continuous?

Tags: differential-geometry

**Question:** Given a [geodesically complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_manifold) regular surface $S\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $p\in S$, there is a well-defined [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)#Definition) $\exp_{p}:T_p S\rightarrow S$ which is a local diffeomorphism at $0\in T_p S$. It seems that $\exp_p$ must be continuous on $T_p S$, but I cannot prove it. I look at my [textbook](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Differential_Geometry_of_Curves_and_Surf/gg2xDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) and see that the author uses a theorem about local solutions of ODE to prove that $\exp_{p}$ is locally smooth and hence locally continuous at $0$. So I don't see how to prove the global continuity of $\exp_{p}$. Could anyone suggest a way to verify the continuity?

Comment: The fact that $S$ is complete means that the solutions of the geodesic equation exist and are smooth for all time. To show $\exp_p$ is smooth, one must show that the solutions of the geodesic equation also depend smoothly on the initial velocity.